# In Codeigniter Pagination's generated page links, page 1 is always selected

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm about to pull my hair over this!

On initial load of my page with pagination (by CI), all rows are displayed, even if I only want 3. On click of other pages, however, it works fine (the correct rows are displayed), but Page 1 is always "selected" (not clickable), even if I click on Page 2, 3, etc.

Any ideas?

My **CONTROLLER**:

```
function album($type, $album_id, $album_name) {

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url("photo_store/album/$type/$album_id/$album_name/");
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Media_model->get_photos($album_id, 'display_date DESC', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $album_photos = $this->Media_model->get_photos($album_id, 'display_date DESC', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(6), FALSE);

    $this->_load_view(array(
        /* some other variables here */
        'album_photos' => $album_photos
    ));

)

private function _load_view($more_data) {
    $data = array_merge($more_data, array( /* some other variables here */ ));
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

My **MODEL**:

```
public function get_photos($album_id=NULL, $order_by='display_date DESC', $limit=NULL, $offset=NULL, $count=FALSE) {

    $result = array();
    $query = $this->db->select('medium.*')->join('medium', "$this->item.medium_id = medium.id", 'inner')->order_by($order_by);
    $limit = $limit ? $limit : '0';
    $offset = $offset ? $offset : '0';
    if ($limit!=='0' && $offset!=='0') {
        $query->limit($limit, $offset);
    }

    if ($album_id) { $result = $query->get_where($this->item, array('album_id' => $album_id)); }
    else { $result = $query->get($this->item); }

    if ($count){ return $result->num_rows(); }
    else { return $result->result(); }

}
```

My **VIEW**:

```
foreach ($album_photos as $photo) {
    //display photos here
}
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Comment: what is `$this->_load_view()` doing?

Comment: @Jakub: nothing important, really. i modified the `controller` part above to include `_load_view()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe part of the problem is coming in here:

```
if ($limit!=='0' && $offset!=='0') {
    $query->limit($limit, $offset);
}
```

Since you don't have an `else` part for your statement, the query is never limited for that first page.

I suggest you change that code to

```
if ($limit!=='0') {
    $query->limit($limit, $offset);
}
```

or even just

```
$query->limit($limit, $offset);
```

since `$limit` should theoretically never be `null` or `0` because you've set it to `3`. `$offset`, unless set, should be `0` so you could replace `null` with it in your model's function,

Comment: your 1st suggestion works (sort of), the 2nd one somehow makes the `create_links()` method not display anything. so now i'm using your 1st suggestion. it sort of works because page 1 now only displays 3 items (yipee!). my new problem is that, since i have 11 results, there should be four pages: (3) (3) (3) (2), however, the last page with 2 items (page 4) does not appear in the generated links. any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you manually navigate to the 4th page, i.e. http://example.com/page/4? Does it give you any error(s) or just display nothing?

Comment: i manually go to the 4th page by `... photo_store/album/category/4/tourism/9` and it works fine, displays the two photos. but still there is no link to page `4`

Comment: Try adding `$config['uri_segment'] = '6';` after `$this->load->library('pagination');` in your Controller.

Comment: hey it works.. but kinda weird though.. when viewing Page 1, links are `1 2 3 >  Last ›`. when viewing Page 4, links are `‹ First  < 2 3 4`. that is, when viewing the first page, the last page is just shown as "Last" and not as a number. And when viewing the last page, the first page is just shown as "First" and not as a number. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: additional: when viewing both Page 2 and 3, links to all four pages are available: `< 1 2 3 4 > ` (but without `First` and `Last`)

Comment: Yes, they're the default values; you can customise the first / last links or use `$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;` so that your actual page numbers will be shown instead. More configuration options available here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Answer (score 3):

You can just add this to the config array so the pagination knows where to find the current page:

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

Comment: Please make sure to notice if the question has an accepted answer and has been active recently before posting a short answer!

Answer (score 1):

When there are more than 3 uri segments passed in the url, selected page of pagination will not be displayed correctly, it will highlight the first page all the time.

Pagination is working, but the selected page is not diplayed correctly.

To solve this, solution:

go to *Pagination.php* file which is located at *system->libraries->Pagination.php*

just simply set

```
var $uri_segment = 4;// or 5 or 6;
```

It will work.

Comment: Editing the system files is always a bad idea. You can always achieve similar results without doing damage by making your own `MY_` controller. In this case `MY_Pagination`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this to the config array so the pagination knows where to find the current page:

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 4; // Your appropriate uri segment: 5 or 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to code your controller like below:

```
public function index($page=''){
//...
$page = ($page!='')? $page : 0;
$config["cur_page"] = $page;

//...

}
```